# Problema con Ubuntu en VirtualBox

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

Desde esta tarde, al intentar iniciar en Ubuntu 16.04 que tengo en Virtual box (uso Windows 10), al hacer login, la pantalla se queda parada, como si no cargase el escritorio. No me deja abrir terminal ni nada... ¿alguien sabe que puede ser?

Comment: Si dentro de la vm presionas ctrl alt f2 (o f3 o f4) sale algo?

Comment: puedo entrar con CTRL + F1 a la terminal y loguearme asi, pero en entorno grafico nada, he probado varias cosas que he leido por internet y no funcionan. ME quede ayer sin espacio en el disco y hoy lo he ampliado, no se si podrá ser por eso